# Does a delete expression invoke the destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I am allocating memory to a object dynamically and then if I call delete what happens?
the destructor is called or delete function has a different way of handling memory?

Consider the following example:

```
class A 
{
 int x;
}

int main()
{
    A *ptr = new A();
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

where is the destructor called?

Comment: Define the destructor inside `A` and see the call!!

Comment: It should be called on the `delete` but you could just set a breakpoint in the destructor and step through.

Comment: Ken, it is good practise to set deleted pointers to `NULL`. If you delete already delete (unallocated) memory it is undefined behaviour, but if you delete a NULL pointer nothing happens. Also you should look into using RAII for all your resource (not just memory) needs.

Comment: It is not good practise to set deleted pointers to NULL, because you can not detect double deletion, which is a bug. After all: use shared_ptr or unique_ptr to manage the lifetime of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression with the delete operator, first calls the appropriate destructor (if needed), and then calls function operator delete to release the storage.
Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete/) for details.

Answer (score 3):

`delete` automatically calls the destructor, and then frees the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `delete` calls the destructor.